# C# Regular Expression matching but not Regexr.com

Tags: c#, regex

Maybe I am doing something wrong here but it seems weird to me that when I try to match the string "radiologic examination eye detect foreign body" against the regular expression "\b*ct\b" on regexr.com then I find no match but when I try and do the same thing using a C# program, it matches. C# code is given below. Am I doing/checking something wrong?

```
string desc = "radiologic examination eye detect foreign body";
string regex = "\\b" + "*ct" + "\\b";
if (Regex.IsMatch(desc, regex))
{
    String x = Regex.Replace(desc, regex, " " + "ct" + " ").Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to filter out? Just the letters "ct" in a word?

Comment: Are you matching before the word Detect? Also if its working whats the issue?:-)

Comment: No I am trying "not to match". The C# code ends up matching "ct" but if you try the same thing on regexr.com then it does not match anything.

Comment: Different strokes for different folks. Each language / implementation can have different expression rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's matching because you've got an asterisk in there.

An asterisk means:

> Matches the preceding character zero or more times

So it's not matching the `\b` at all, but still satisfying the above condition.

Remove this and it no longer matches:

```
string regex = "\\b" + "ct" + "\\b";
```

Comment: @mattytommo - back on the stack ;)

Comment: @DarrenDavies Can't stay away from a bit of regex mate :D

Answer (score 1):

C# is probably interpreting `\b*` as 0 or more word boundaries.

Since this is an odd definition, maybe regexr is disallowing the contruct and treating it as `\b`. For instance this could be the case if it is using a different regex backend and a translation to C#.

Are you sure you didn't mean `\b.*ct\b` which would be a word boundary followed by any number of characters followed by ct and another word boundary?

Comment: Ya actually the regex is not made by me. It's coming in with a set of words I am processing. Thanks!